# How set-up ci/cd in git to transfer changes from git to local place in my pc?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a git repository and I want whenever I commit a code to my master branch that change apply to my production server.
I already set-up my git runner but I dont know how should I set-up my yml file to do this file transfering between git and production server.

Thank you

Comment: provide more details about your production environment, which language you are using, how do you deploy today etc..

Comment: my prod server is a linux server and they are bash scripts.

Comment: Gitlab CI has very good documentation and lots of [examples](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/). Your question is broad, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)